# How to remap keys to modified keys using hidutil in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, key-bindings

how can I remap certain keys from normal state to a modified one?

I want to press 'a' on my USB keyboard and get an 'ALT-a'.

I tried this but it does absolutely nothing.

```
hidutil property --matching '{"ProductID":0x760a}' --set '{"UserKeyMapping": 
 [
 {"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x000700000007,
 "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x000700004007},
 ]
}'
```

On the whole planet no one seems to have the same problem as I couldn't find anything how to do it with modifier keys. Maybe it is not possible at all?

Before someone asks: I use an additional keyboard for video editing and want shortcuts such as CMD-S be bound on the S-Key.